# There's a way to refetch fullcalendar in v3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs

I don't want to refetch fullcalendar events. I have a ajax which refresh the `var date` and I want to refresh the fullcalendar to set new maxDate and minDate to the calendar. The way I'm doing the values changes, but the maxDate and minDate of the calendar doesn't work

```
let date = {
    'maxDate': moment().toDate(),
    'minDate': moment().subtract(365, "days").toDate()
};

$('#calendar').fullcalendar({
    // [...]
        minDate: date['minDate'],
        maxDate: date['maxDate'],
    // [...]
});

// [...]

$("#input_calendar").on('change', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('calendarioOferta.datas') }}",
        method: "GET",
        data: {
            'calendar': $(this).val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            date = data;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: On your `success` call, what does `data` return?

Comment: An object: {maxDate: "2018-07-11 00:00:00", minDate: "2018-04-11 00:00:00"​}

Comment: OK, and if you log `date` after setting `date = data;` what does it log?

Comment: Object { maxDate: "2018-07-11 00:00:00", minDate: "2018-04-11 00:00:00" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you will need to just set the calendar on your success call. Right now you are just changing the `var date` to be set to your `data` on success, but nothing is saying to reset the full calendar.

```
var setFullCalendar = function(dateData) { 
  $('#calendar').fullcalendar({
    // [...]
        minDate: dateData['minDate'],
        maxDate: dateData['maxDate'],
    // [...]
  });
}

$("#input_calendar").on('change', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('calendarioOferta.datas') }}",
        method: "GET",
        data: {
            'calendar': $(this).val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            setFullCalendar(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, I'm readying the docs, really looks like I need set new variable on calendar, as you do, but your solution still doesn't work. I'm trying to see this [visibleRange](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/visibleRange), because minDate and maxDate maybe doesn't work in fullcalendar v3

Comment: @itepifanio Yeah, minDate and maxDate don't exist in v3. But...bearing in mind that you're not setting any view options, the default view type is "month". So it will always display exactly one month of data. Even visibleRange doesn't affect it. visibleRange will only affect "agenda", "list" and "basic" type views, not month.

Comment: @itepifanio P.S. Here's a demo  where visibleRange has no effect because the view is "month": http://jsfiddle.net/yds5gLmq/1/. And here's a demo of it working nicely with an "agenda" view: http://jsfiddle.net/yds5gLmq/2/

Comment: @itepifanio P.P.S. Once you have set up the calendar, if you want to change an option you don't need to re-create the calendar, you can just use the "option" command - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dynamic-options . Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pdztxr8f/

Comment: @itepifanio In fact as far as I can see, "minDate" and "maxDate" options don't exist in _any_ version of fullCalendar. Where did you get the idea from to use those? Can you link me to the right documentation about it??

Comment: @ADyson I see the minDate in a answer, but don't remember where if in the stackoverflow or the github issues, I've search in the docs, they really don't exists. Well, the visible range does'nt wok as well with my fullcalendar because the type is agendaWeek.

Comment: @itepifanio Maybe you're confusing it with minTime and maxTime which do exist (but have a different purpose than you are wanting here). Anyway, it's totally logical that visibleRange doesn't  work with  agendaWeek. The  clue is in the name - it's fixed to work in weeks, therefore you can't customise the date range to show a different number of days or a different start. It will always display exactly one week starting on whichever day is in the options as being the first day of the week. Just change it to "agenda" only (like in the demo I gave you a link to above) and it will work fine.